# SpriteKit EXC_BAD_ACCESS NSTimer

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nstimer

I have a GameScene which I implement in GameViewController. GameViewController contains back button over game scene. So when I finish my game I have an NSTimer with 2 sec delay.

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(playAnimation)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
```

But if I tap on back button my view controller pop back, but even after pop to previous view controller there is still music from game scene and after my timer will try to invoke it causes bad access, because scene seems already deallocated.

So I never reach dealloc method in game scene where I can invalidate my timer.

Comment: Can you not add all your shutdown code in `viewWillDisappear`?

Answer (score 0):

> target   The object to which to send the message specified by
>   aSelector when the timer fires. The timer maintains a strong reference
>   to target until it (the timer) is invalidated.

So I guess view controller will never get de-allocated, before your timer fires.

So can't you invalidate timer in viewWillDisappear?

Comment: the timer it is a part of game scene, but seem like game scene lives some time before it will get dealloc message. I suppose it's because of SKAction playSoundFileNamed: method. So while it play sound scene is in the memory.

Comment: can you paste the code and point out the line which causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SKAction that plays sound in the game and after even I dismiss my view controller seems like Game Scene still in the memory because of the playing sound. But when sound was finished game scene seems got a dealloc, but timer still wait for its invocation, I think it causes bad access.